# How to colour a curve differently in every new slide in beamer using an argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, color, slideshow

I am preparing a lecture note on sequences of functions. There I want to add graphs of the functions as each term of the sequence. The following MWE is a snippet of the code I am using currently.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\usetheme{EastLansing}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{beetle}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Sequences of functions}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
                    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (1.1,0);
                    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.1);
                    \foreach \n in {1,2,...,10}
                    {
                        \onslide<+->
                        {
                            \draw [yellow, samples=100, domain=0:1] plot (\x,{(\x)^(\n)});
                        }
                    }
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$ f_n(x)=x^{n} $}
            \end{figure}
            \column{0.5\linewidth}\pause
            \begin{figure}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2.5]
                    \draw [->] (-3.14,0) -- (3.14,0);
                    \draw [->] (0,-1.1) -- (0,1.1);
                    \foreach \n in {1,2,...,10}
                    {
                        \onslide<+->
                        {
                            \draw [yellow, samples=100, domain=-3.14:3.14] plot (\x,{(sin((\n*\x)r))/\n});
                        }
                    }
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$ f_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{n} $}
            \end{figure}
        \end{columns}       
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I want here is to change the colour of the newly added graph in each slide. I understand that that can be achieved by inserting another loop like

```
\foreach \k in {1,...,\n}
\draw [red, samples=100, domain=0:1] plot (\x,{(\x)^(\k)});
```

But in this way, the rendering time shoots up uncontrollably. That is a point of concern also because I will add a few more sequences. Now to tackle this, I happen to have this thought of controlling the `draw` colour (`yellow` here) with `\n`. But I have no idea how this can be achieved (or whether is possible at all!). Please help.

> **PS:** Any other way to achieve the goal without increasing rendering time is also welcome.

Comment: I just discovered that adding `opacity={0.1*\n}` as a `draw` option works as expected but the first few graphs are almost invisible. Can there be some solution like using `\color{yellow!{10*\n}!red}` as an option in `draw`? This particular string did not work btw.

Comment: For that string, use `\foreach[evaluate=\n as \tint using 10*\n] ...` then use `yellow!\tint!red`.  You can use macros in colour mixing but not expressions.  (Though it's probably possible to use a `\numexpr` version for simple expressions.)

Comment: @AndrewStacey Hey thanks! This works as desired. Why don't you post this solution as an answer so that I can upvote and award the bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code compiles in 10 seconds.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt,notheorems]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach\n in{1,...,10}{
        \path[save path=\temppowerpath]
            plot[scale=5,samples=100,domain=0:1](\x,{(\x)^(\n)});
        \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname powerpath\n\endcsname=\temppowerpath
    }
    \foreach\n in{1,...,10}{
        \path[save path=\tempsinepath]
            plot[yscale=2.5,samples=100,domain=-3.14:3.14](\x,{(sin((\n*\x)r))/\n});
        \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname sinepath\n\endcsname=\tempsinepath
    }

\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{frame}{Sequences of functions}

    $$\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (1.1,0);
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.1);
        \foreach\n in{1,...,10}{
            \expandafter\let\expandafter\temppowerpath\csname powerpath\n\endcsname
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nplusone{\n+1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\tenn{10*\n}
            \draw<\nplusone-22>[use path=\temppowerpath,yellow!\tenn!green];
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2.5]
        \draw [->] (-3.14,0) -- (3.14,0);
        \draw [->] (0,-1.1) -- (0,1.1);
        \foreach\n in {1,...,10}{
            \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempsinepath\csname sinepath\n\endcsname
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\npluseleven{\n+11}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\tenn{10*\n}
            \draw<\npluseleven-22>[use path=\tempsinepath,yellow!\tenn!green];
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}$$
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, your answer contains too many things which are unknown to me. So it will be tough and cumbersome for me to edit your codes for other examples. I will go with Andrew Stacey's solution. But, of course, your answer is technically correct and does solve my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh that's pretty!!

Comment: For my tastes :-) it is very fast ...+1...excellent work.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to emphasise the different functions.  In the first, I use the `evaluate` key to calculate a tint factor that can be used in a colour declaration, thus making it possible to use an expression in such a colour declaration.  In the second, I use the TikZ library `overlay-beamer-styles` to modify a style depending on which slide it is on.

So in the first set of functions, the colours vary but each individual function always has the same colour in all slides.  In the second set, the newest function is highlighted yellow and all the others are red.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/568629/86}
\usetheme{EastLansing}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{beetle}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tikzset{
  conditional~ style/.code~ n~ args={3}{
    \int_compare:nTF {#1}
    {\pgfkeysalso{#2}}
    {\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Sequences of functions}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
                    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (1.1,0);
                    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.1);
                    \foreach[evaluate=\n as \tint using 10*\n] \n in {1,2,...,10}
                    {
                        \onslide<+->
                        {
                            \draw [yellow!\tint!red, samples=100, domain=0:1] plot (\x,{(\x)^(\n)});
                        }
                    }
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$ f_n(x)=x^{n} $}
            \end{figure}
            \column{0.5\linewidth}\pause
            \begin{figure}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2.5]
                    \draw [->] (-3.14,0) -- (3.14,0);
                    \draw [->] (0,-1.1) -- (0,1.1);
                    \foreach \n in {1,2,...,10}
                    {
                        \onslide<+->
                        {
                          \draw [
                            alt=<.>{yellow}{red},
                            conditional style={\n = 10}{yellow}{},
                            samples=100,
                            domain=-3.14:3.14
                          ] plot (\x,{(sin((\n*\x)r))/\n});
                        }
                    }
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$ f_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{n} $}
            \end{figure}
        \end{columns}
        \pause
        \pause
        \pause
        \pause
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*Added in edit:* I've added an extra style `conditional on` which can be used to conditionally apply a style.  There are a variety of ways to get the last function to stay yellow with extra stuff on the slide, the extra style `conditional on` is just one of them.

[image: Highlighted functions in beamer]

Comment: An extra thank for the second solution. Loved it! One follow up question on the second method. Please find my actual code for one slide [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/Junw7rkM). How do I keep the `yellow` colour for the last graph throughout the rest of the slides of the same frame? Shall I superimpose that with another redrawing of `\draw [yellow, samples=100, domain=0:1] plot (\x,{(\x)^(20)})` after the `\foreach` loop? Or is there a better and elegant solution?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul There are a lot of ways to accomplish that.  I've added a suggestion to my code in this answer.  Your suggestion in the comment is a fairly standard way to achieve this as well.